# accesing contents of uitableview cell in another class

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i have a class loginViewController which has table contents. i have loaded a custom cell to each row of the table. in method cellForRowAtIndexPath i have created a button for each row and asigned it a tag value. clicking on this button takes us to new view controller logininsidesViewController. Now in logininsidesViewController class i want to access the button tag i created earlier.what should i do?

***loginViewController.m class***

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    customcell *cell=(customcell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellcstm"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(customActionPressed)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_black.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(275 ,9, 25, 25);
    [cell addSubview:button];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        //[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"customcell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellcstm"];

        NSArray *arr12=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customcell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[arr12 objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<=indexPath.row; i++)
    {
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell.lbl.hidden=YES;
        UILabel *l=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        l.text=@"Login Templates";
        l.frame=CGRectMake(100, 15, 180, 28);

        [cell.contentView addSubview:l];
    }

    if (indexPath.row==1)
    {  
        button.tag=1;
        cell.img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
        cell.lbl.text=@"Facebook";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    if (indexPath.row==2)
    {
        button.tag=2;
        cell.img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"g+.png"];
        cell.lbl.text=@"Google";

        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    if (indexPath.row==3)
    {
        button.tag=3;
        cell.img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"youtube.png"];
        cell.lbl.text=@"Youtube";

        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    if (indexPath.row==4)
    {
        button.tag=4;
        cell.img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"];
        cell.lbl.text=@"Twitter";

        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    if (indexPath.row==5)
    {
        button.tag=5;
        cell.img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"flicker.png"];
        cell.lbl.text=@"Flicker";

        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    else
    {
        cell .textLabel.text= [logarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

i want to access the button.tag in my logininsidesViewController class. plz help

Answer (score 1):

In continuation with Viruss's answer you can create a property with integer type in `logininsidesViewController` class and pass that from button click.

```
-(IBAction) customActionPressed:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"button tag:%d",[sender tag]);
    logininsidesViewController *objLoginInside = [[logininsidesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"logininsidesViewController" bundle:nil];
    objLoginInside.buttonTag = sender.tag;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objLoginInside animated:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add One target method to your buttons and access it with tags,

In cellForRow method Update to this.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You can access here with tag,

```
-(IBAction) customActionPressed:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"button tag:%d",[sender tag]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your `button` on cell and again you're adding it on cell's `contentView` correct that is the problem.

If you want adding it in `cell.contentView` you must provide allocation in each if condition and then add it

**Edit:** Do smart coding

```
viewDidLoad()



[self.myTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  arImage = @[@"facebook.png", @"g+.png", @"twitter.png", @"flicker.png" ];
  arLables = @[@"Facebook", @"GooglePlus", @"Tweeter", @"Flicker"];

cellForRowAtIndexPath

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell * cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_black.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(275 ,9, 25, 25);


    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell.lblText1.hidden=YES;
        UILabel *l=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        l.text=@"Login Templates";
        l.frame=CGRectMake(100, 15, 180, 28);

        [cell.contentView addSubview:l];
    }



    if ( indexPath.row > 0 && indexPath.row <= 5) {
        button.tag = indexPath.row;

        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:arImage[indexPath.row - 1]];
        cell.textLabel.text=[arLables objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    } else {
         cell.textLabel.text= [logarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    return cell;
}
```